# CdkDragDrop and ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular7, angular-material-7

I'm trying to use Drag&Drop features relased with Angular Material 7.

I separated my template in reusable pieces using `ngTemplateOutlet` and every option can be either a **Thing**™ or a nested **Thing**™ which have some more **sub-Things**™.

Nested **Things**™ are displayed as an expansion panel.
I want all the first-level **Things**™ to be re-orderable as if thery were a list.

(*Ok, ok, it's obvious that's a reorderable sidenav with normal and nested options, just pretend it's not so obvious*)

This is the code I initially wrote.

```
<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="dropItem($event)" lockAxis="y">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let thing of things">
      <ng-container
        *ngTemplateOutlet="!thing.children ? singleThing : multipleThing; context: { $implicit: thing }"
      ></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #singleThing let-thing>
  <div cdkDrag>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="thingTemplate; context: { $implicit: thing }"></ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #multipleOption let-thing>
  <mat-expansion-panel cdkDrag (cdkDropListDropped)="dropItem($event)">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        <p>Nested thing title</p>
        <span cdkDragHandle></span>
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let childThing of thing.children">
      <div class="childThing">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="thingTemplate; context: { $implicit: childThing }"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #thingTemplate let-thing>
  <p>I'm a thing!</p>
  <span cdkDragHandle></span>
</ng-template>
```

Problem: single **Things**™ are draggable, but they are not enforced as a list like cdkDropList should do, I can just drag them around everywhere.

I had a similar problem some time ago when trying to use template outlets and putting `ng-template`s back into the 'HTML flow' worked to solve that, so I tried the same.

```
<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="dropItem($event)" lockAxis="y">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let thing of things">
      <ng-container
        *ngIf="!thing.children; then singleThing; else multipleThing"
      ></ng-container>
        <ng-template #singleThing>
          <div cdkDrag>
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="thingTemplate; context: { $implicit: thing }"></ng-container>
          </div>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template #multipleOption>
          <mat-expansion-panel cdkDrag (cdkDropListDropped)="dropItem($event)">
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title>
                <p>Nested thing title</p>
                <span cdkDragHandle></span>
              </mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>

            <ng-container *ngFor="let childThing of thing.children">
              <div class="childThing">
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="thingTemplate; context: { $implicit: childThing }"></ng-container>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
        </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #thingTemplate let-thing>
  <p>I'm a thing!</p>
  <span cdkDragHandle></span>
</ng-template>
```

And, of course why not, it works!
Yeah, fine, but **why**?

Not much changed, we used a `ngIf` instead of the first `ngTemplateOutlet` and removed context bindings for the **Thing**™ because now both templates have its local variable reference thanks to the shared scope.

So, why exactly does it work in the second way and not in the first one?

Bonus points: is it possible to make it work keeping the first code structure which, to me, seems obviously more readable and clean?

Comment: did you find any work around, facing same issue ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, I even reported this as an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/14798).

It turns out to be caused by the separateness of `cdkDropList` from `cdkDrag`. `cdkDrag` must be in a tag nested inside the one with `cdkDropList`, otherwise the dragged element won't detect the drop zone.

The solution in your case would be an additional `<div cdkDrag>` below `cdkDropList`, and only under that you would call the template with `ngTemplateOutlet`.

Comment: I suspected that, unluckily I have to keep cdkDrag separated on the two different elements so I'll stick with the less clean option. But thank for the explanation and the link, marking this as best answer