# Drag & drop between two tree view lists

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I have one tree view (nested) list with angular material drag&drop functionality: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-nested-drag-drop-tree-structure-a9fm7a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fdata.ts)

But I need to have 2 treeview lists with ability to drag&drop elements between those lists.

Could somebody help?

Comment: Hi @Lukas, did you try this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130044/angular-materials-drag-and-drop-between-lists-if-theres-no-data-model

Comment: Hello, this not meet my expectations because I need treeview lists