# cdkDropList with ng-template on dynamic component list do'snt work

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular7

I'm trying to use Drag&Drop features released with Angular Material 7. And dynamically creating component using ng-tempalte.

`<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="dropLocal($event)">
          <ng-template  #components></ng-template>
</div>`

and added cdkDrag at components.

I am using createComponent at parent component to keep on create components.
`viewContainerRef.createComponent`

but dragdrop functionality is not functional since  `cdkDrag must be in a tag nested inside the one with cdkDropList, otherwise the dragged element won't detect the drop zone.`

reference :https://stackoverflow.com/a/54158293/4481952

Is there a way around to make dropfunctionality work?

demo code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngtemplate-reorder?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngtemplate-reorder?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you can't use cdkDrag and cdkDropList with componenet , we have to use service for that which is recently released with AngularMaterial 3.5.+

`CdkDrag uses dependency injection to find out whether it's inside a CdkDropList which doesn't work when the template is inside a different component. For more advanced cases like this one you can use the DragDrop service to attach the drag&drop functionality yourself.`

Refer https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/15553

Stackblitz code for implementation of cdkService:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngtemplate-reorder-7i6uuk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

hope this helps out someone else.