# Angular - DragDropModule not working inside templates

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I would like to use **DragDropModule** for my angular application so I can move panels that are stored inside **templates** (for practical purposes as well as for recursive plotting of child elements).

The problem that I have is that cdkDrag can't find the correct cdkDropList to drop into if cdkDrag is hidden within a template and is not directly nested under the HTML element. Example:

```
<div
cdkDropList
[cdkDropListData]="expanded.activities"
(cdkDropListDropped)="dropActivity($event)">

    <div *ngFor="let activity of expanded.activities">
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="orangeProgramActivity"></ng-container>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-template #orangeProgramActivity>
    <div cdkDrag>This is just a test</div>
</ng-template>
```

With this code example, the orangeProgramActivity can be dragged anywhere but doesn't drop into the correct dropList as cdkDrag keyword can't find any droplist within its own template.

In the second example, everything works correctly and the item gets dropped into correct dropList:

```
<div
cdkDropList
[cdkDropListData]="expanded.activities"
(cdkDropListDropped)="dropActivity($event)">

    <div *ngFor="let activity of expanded.activities">
        <div cdkDrag>This is just a test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to achieve the same functionality as in the second example, but with the use of templates because I really need them for recursion. Unfortunately, I can't reveal the whole code as my employer wouldn't be happy with that.

All I need is some static reference for my cdkDrag that is inside a template, to point onto a correct element with dropList that is outside of the template.

These are the only solutions that I found on the internet and they don't seem to work for me:
[Material 7 Drag and Drop ng-template incompatibility](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14798)
[CdkDragDrop and ngTemplateOutlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53210886/cdkdragdrop-and-ngtemplateoutlet)

This is my first question on Stack Overflow and I'm new to angular, so I'm sorry for any confusion in my post, and thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not work for all use cases, but you could just write it like this:

```html
<div
cdkDropList
[cdkDropListData]="expanded.activities"
(cdkDropListDropped)="dropActivity($event)">

    <div *ngFor="let activity of expanded.activities" cdkDrag>
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="orangeProgramActivity"></ng-container>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-template #orangeProgramActivity>
    <div>This is just a test</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Yes, that seems like the only good option, but it would be super useful if we could at least make a handle inside a template for more complex structures. 
I guess that I will create another container with a handle icon and my template and with CSS I will style my handle to where I want it to be. I will post the result here once I make it.

Answer (score 1):

I was lucky that **I only need to reorder elements inside an array** in which they are and I don't need to transfer them into other containers. So for my "root" activities, I used your simple solution to wrap it all in a draggable element.

```
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="expanded.activities" (cdkDropListDropped)="dropActivity($event)">

<!-- For every object in array make a container with template and an icon that will serve as a handle -->
<div *ngFor="let activity of expanded.activities">

    <div cdkDrag>
        <div cdkDragHandle>
            <!-- Handle icon from FontAwesome -->
            <i class="fas fa-grip-vertical"></i>
        </div>

        <!-- Container with a template that we need -->
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="orangeProgramActivity" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{act: activity}"></ng-container>
    </div>
    <!-- Recursive template for children -->
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="childActivitiesRecursion" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{act: activity}"></ng-container>

</div>
```

And for my **recursion**, I created a **droplist inside a template** that serves **only for reordering** these children activities.
(I had problems with pasting template so the ng-template tag is not terminated at the end of the code)

```
<ng-template let-act="act" #childActivitiesRecursion>

<!-- Droplist inside a template for reordering child activites -->
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="act.childActivities" (cdkDropListDropped)="dropActivity($event)">

    <!-- Iterates through all child activities -->
    <div *ngFor="let childActivity of act.childActivities">

        <div cdkDrag>
            <div cdkDragHandle>
                <i class="fas fa-grip-vertical"></i>
            </div>
            <!-- Different template for child activities -->
            <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="blueProgramActivity" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{act: childActivity}"></ng-container>
        </div>
        <!-- Recursion for even deeper child activites -->
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="childActivitiesRecursion" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{act: childActivity}"></ng-container>

    </div>
</div>
```

I will accept Richard's answer as a solution because if you are able to solve it like this, it's definitely the most elegant solution you can do. But there would be still an **issue if you needed to transfer items into different containers after using templates for recursion!**